# What proverb describes getting out from trouble but ending up in another one?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, proverbs, proverb-requests

I remember reading something like "out from something's mouth/jaws (like a dragon) and into another..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a dragon, but it's nevertheless very warm:

#### Out of the frying pan into the fire

> The phrase **out of the frying pan into the fire** is used to describe the situation of moving or getting from a bad or difficult situation to a worse one, often as the result of trying to escape from the bad or difficult one.

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_frying_pan_into_the_fire))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the expression:

***from bad to worse*** idiom

> from a bad state or condition to an even worse state or condition
>
> - The company has been struggling for years, and things have recently gone from bad to worse.  (M-W)

Comment: Good suggestion, but the OP is after a proverb.

Answer (score 2):

You may have read someone riffing off the phase 'caught between Scylla and Charybdis'

> Being between Scylla and Charybdis is an idiom deriving from Greek mythology, which has been associated with the proverbial advice "to choose the lesser of two evils".[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis) Several other idioms, such as "on the horns of a dilemma", "between the devil and the deep blue sea", and "between a rock and a hard place" express similar meanings.[2] The mythical situation also developed a proverbial use in which seeking to choose between equally dangerous extremes is seen as leading inevitably to disaster. 
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis)

Scylla being a shoal of rocks represented in mythology as a six headed monster and Charybdis being a whirlpool represented as a monster who lived under a rock in the sea.

According to wikipedia

> Erasmus recorded it in his Adagia (1515) under the Latin form of evitata Charybdi in Scyllam incidi (having escaped Charybdis I fell into Scylla)

It's easy to imagine someone familiar with this jazzing it up to something like, 'I freed myself from the jaws of Scylla only to be dragged straight down into the whirlpool of Charybdis'.